# How to visualise a tiny neural network as a function

Tags: neural-networks, intercept, function

Say you have the simplest possible neural network with 1 input, 1 output and 1 hidden variable as depicted below. In this case, the activation function is logistic.
 [image]

I assume between x and y, the logistic function here is $\frac{1}{1+exp(-(ax+b))}$.
Beyond that, I don't know  how they combine between layers. I had assumed that z = logistic(cy+d) where y=logistic(ax+b), but from plotting this manually against the neural network output, it appears to not be the case.

Furthermore, I have no idea how the input from multiple nodes gets transformed into the output of a single node. For the neural network below:[image]

How do the functions describing the individual neurons combine? Does z = logistic(ey1+fy2+g), or logistic(ey1) + logistic(fy2) + g or something else?

Using the coefficients a,b,c,d,e,f,g, how would you write the output z as a function of x?

This has been bugging me for a while and I would really appreciate some clarification on this. I understand that writing the formula for a neural network of any appreciable size would be both intractable and unhelpful, I just want to get an understanding of the underlying maths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a unit of a typical neural network, you always:

1. Compute weighted sum of all its inputs, including the bias term
2. Apply the activation function

So in your first example, $y=\sigma(ax+b)$ and $z=\sigma(cy+d)$. If this does not match, make sure the unit $y$ really computes a sigmoid and it is not only a linear unit.

In your second example, $z = \sigma(ey_1+fy_2+g)$.

Note that it is not really infeasible to write a formula for a large network, you just use matrix operations and the following recursive formula:
$$\mathbf{y}_\ell=\sigma(W_\ell\mathbf{y}_{\ell-1}+\mathbf{b}_\ell),$$
where $\mathbf{y}_\ell$ is the vector of activations in $\ell$-th layer ($\mathbf{y}_0$ is the input), $W_\ell$ is the weight matrix in layer $\ell$, whose element at position $i,j$ corresponds to the weight between $i$-th unit in the layer $\ell-1$ and $j$-th unit in layer $\ell$; finally, $\mathbf{b}_\ell$ is the bias vector.